# Representation of rationals as finite continued fractions with restricted coefficients

Tags: number-theory, rational-numbers, continued-fractions

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2180384/96384) and its answer incidentally show that every non-zero rational number $q$ can be written as a *finite generalised continued fraction* of the form:

$$  \dfrac{2^{n_0}}{1- \dfrac{2^{n_1}}{1 - \dfrac{2^{n_2}}{1- \dfrac{2^{n_3}}{\ddots\dfrac{\ddots}{1-2^{n_{r(q)}}}}}}}$$

with $n_i \in \Bbb N$ and $r(q) \ge 1$ depending on $q$. For example:
$$ \frac{14}{9} = \dfrac2{1- \dfrac2{1 -  8}} $$
and

$$\frac{9}{5} = \dfrac1{1- \dfrac4{1 -  \dfrac8{1- 2}}} $$
and
$$-17 = \dfrac1{1- \dfrac2{1 -  \dfrac8{1- \dfrac2{1-\dfrac4{1-\dfrac4{1-2}}}}}}$$

(How to get the powers of $2$: Let $v_2$ be the [$2$-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order), then if $v_2(q) \ge 0$, set $n_i = v_2(f^i(q))$; if $v_2(q) <0$, set $n_0=0, n_{i+1}= v_2(f^i\circ g(q))$ where $f(x)= 1-\frac{1}{x|x|_2}$ and $g(x) = 1-\frac{1}{x}$ are the functions in that question resp. answer.)

Now, if we generalise from $2$ to an arbitrary natural $k > 1$ (in particular *prime* $k$, but why restrict to that), I wondered if it is also true that:

> For every $ q \in \Bbb Q^*$ there is a finite tuple $(n_0, ..., n_{r(q)})$ such that
> $$  q = \dfrac{k^{n_0}}{1- \dfrac{k^{n_1}}{1 - \dfrac{k^{n_2}}{1- \dfrac{k^{n_3}}{\ddots\dfrac{\ddots}{1-k^{n_{r(q)}}}}}}}$$

or something similar/more general (what if the "$1$"'s are replaced by another natural number etc).

> If not, which rationals can be written that way?

Also, as I basically know nothing about continued fractions and made up an ad hoc approach for the other question, so:

> Are there standard tools for handling this kind of question from the theory of continued fractions?

**Edit**: After playing around a bit, it seems more natural to me (albeit I've neither proven sufficiency nor necessity) that for general $k$, one would allow a set of representatives modulo $k$ instead of the leading "$1$"'s, i.e.

$$  q = \dfrac{k^{n_0}}{b_1- \dfrac{k^{n_1}}{b_2 - \dfrac{k^{n_2}}{b_3- \dfrac{k^{n_3}}{\ddots\dfrac{\ddots}{b_{n_q}-k^{n_{r(q)}}}}}}}$$

with the $b_i \in \{1,2, ..., k-1\}$. This would make a characterisation of the ones where all $b_i=1$ more subtle.

Comment: The continued fraction with "+"s isn't going to get you any negative rational numbers. Additionally, it appears that you are allowing for the possibility of infinite continued fractions. My gut says each fraction will terminate, although I have nothing resembling a proof of that yet. Edited to add: Never mind, despite the ellipses, you say the tuples are finite.

Comment: @SteveB: Tried to correct both issues now (the "+" was wrong anyway, I thought it corresponded to $f(x) = 1+\frac{1}{x|x|_2}$, but it doesn't, sign error). Robert: $-17$ has the expansion it says, and $85/47= \dfrac1{1- \dfrac{2}{1 - \dfrac2{1- \dfrac4{1- \dfrac4{1- \dfrac2{1 - \dfrac4{1- \dfrac8{1-2}}}}}}}}$. As stated, *every* non-zero rational. I honestly do not understand anything else you write.

Comment: I have a proof by induction, but the formatting is taking more time than the math and it won't fit into the time between now and HEB closing.

Comment: My induction proof fell through.

Comment: Did you verify any empirical data on convergence for other primes ?

Comment: Also, I have seen literature on fractions of the form $2^{n_0}-\dfrac1{2^{n_1}-\dfrac1{2^{n_2}-\dfrac1{2^{n_3}-\ldots}}}$.  Do these rearrange to your format?

Comment: @samerivertwice: I have not tried anything empirical, whatever that would mean precisely (I'd be happy to see something). As to that other form, good question; I do not know.

Comment: By empirical I just meant e.g. drop in the prime $3$ and run a Python script for a thousand or so rationals and see if they all converge. I don't trust my coding skills. I'll ask someone.

Comment: FWIW I did some algebra and I think your continued fraction rearranges to $\dfrac1{2^{-n_0}-\dfrac{1}{2^{n_0-n_1}-\dfrac{1}{2^{n_1-n_2}-\dfrac{1}{2^{n_2-n_3}-\ldots}}}}$ and that's now in the more recognised form (except with minus signs) for standard *simple* continued fractions. Obviously one can lose the first $\dfrac1x$ to get its reciprocal.

Comment: ...and here is some reference material on your base $2$ continued fractions. The top pdf covers these https://www.google.com/search?q=Continued+Logarithms+And+Associated+ContinuedFractions