# What are the bounds on the frequency of divisions by 2 in the Collatz cycles of natural numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, collatz-conjecture

If $T^n(x):\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ is the $n^{th}$ iterate of the Collatz function $T(x)=\frac12(3x+1)$ if $x$ odd and $x/2$ if $x$ even.   Then let $Q(x):\Bbb N\to2^{\Bbb N}$ be the parity vector function given by $$Q(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^n(T^n(x)\pmod2)$$

$Q(x)$ is an *infinite* binary string containing a $1$ every time $x$'s Collatz sequence is odd and a $0$ every time it is even, for any natural number $x$.

> As an aside, $Q$ is a partial function of a larger $\Bbb Z_2\to\Bbb Z_2$ bijection which is a 2-adic isometry.

Let $0\leq r(x)\leq1$ denote the proportion of digits of $Q(x)$ which are zeroes, and equivalently the proportion of steps in $x$'s Collatz sequence which are even.  Therefore for all integers whose Collatz sequences stabilise finitely to the well known cycle $(2,1\ldots)$ we have $r(x)=\frac12$

Let $\overline {\Bbb N}$ indicate the subset of natural numbers whose Collatz sequences eventually stabilise to a cyclic orbit. Now suppose $x\in\overline {\Bbb N}$ is a natural number greater than $2$ and $T(x)$ has an eventually cyclic orbit which is not $(2,1\ldots)$.  Under these suppositions I have fairly easily shown that $r(x)=\frac12$ is an upper bound for $r(\overline {\Bbb N})$ - the proof is not too long to give, if required.  In fact $$\log_6(2)<r(x)<\frac12$$

**Question**

> Since the proof was so easy and my talent is so little, I presume this is known and that there are already sharper bounds on $r(\overline {\Bbb N})$.  What bounds on $r(\overline {\Bbb N})$ are known or provable with current techology?

The larger the $x$, the greater the cycle length and the sharper the upper bound will need to be, with $r(x)$ approaching its lower bound $\log_6(2)$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: $T$ is normally defined on natural numbers only, and $\Bbb Z_2$ most commonly means just $\{0, 1\}$ with addition and multiplication mod $2$. It is only later by context that we puzzle out you meant $\Bbb Z_2$ to be the 2-adic integers and $T$ to be defined on them. At that point, we have to go back and re-interpret your post, which is annoying. Please introduce the appropriate context at the start.

Comment: @PaulSinclair sorry for the inconvenience.  Is there a standard notation for the set of binary strings?  $\Bbb N\to \{binary strings\}$ might be less offputting than saying 2-adic numbers. Also, I was taught only to ever use $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ for the integers mod $2$ so as to avoid confusion with $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: $2^{\Bbb N}$ would be the set of binary strings (In this context, "$2$" $\equiv \{0,1\}$). But using 2-adics was not the problem. The problem was not making it clear at the beginning that you are using 2-adics. What you were taught about notations is irrelevant. What is relevant is what you can expect your audience to have been taught. I recommend you edit the problem to say "Collatz function $T(x)=\frac 12(3x+1)$ if $x$ odd and $\frac x2$ if $x$ even, *extended to the 2-adic integers* $\Bbb Z_2.$" Then you have told your audience where you are working and what your notation means.

Comment: That said, you don't seem to use any properties of 2-adics in this, so dropping them would open your audience to people unfamiliar or uncomfortable with them.

Comment: Thanks @PaulSinclair .  Hopefully the latest edit resolves this problem. Re your last point, I agree the 2-adic thing is offputting for some people. It's only used here as a device for containing infinite binary strings but the isometry is a useful aside to be aware of.

Comment: [This portion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Cycles) of the wikipedia article on the Collatz conjecture seems relevant, though it doesn't directly answer your question. Is your proof based on the continued fraction expansion of $\log_6 2$? In particular, [this is the key article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9390052U?via%3Dihub)

Comment: Thanks @PaulSinclair the first link looks relevant.  The $\log_6(2)$ comes from a multiplicative quotient over $\Bbb R$ in which I set $x\sim 2^i3^jx$ and it follows fairly quickly. However thanks for the 2nd link as I have some algebraic descriptions of the Collatz problem whose logical next step demands some continued fraction theory so perhaps there will be something in there I can make use of.

Comment: I noticed that in theorem 2.1 he produces two inequalities on what I think is $\frac 1{r(x)}$ in your notation.

Comment: Thanks @PaulSinclair fwiw, if you're interested in Collatz conjecture these two questions relate to the possible role of continued fractions in Collatz-like problems: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855057/ and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2180384/ .  $f(x)$ in the 2nd link there is a Collatz-like function I worked out that terminates for all rationals, and Torsten's proof of that leads on to prove that the continued fractions of the form he gives biject with the rationals.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for me the massaging of the Collatz-formulae is easier if we assume the "Syracuse"-style notation of the Collatz-iteration
$$ a_{k+1}= {3a_k+1\over 2^{A_1}} \qquad a_k \small \text{ from the odd integers}
$$ and for a $N$-fold iterated transformation the short, vectorial, notation:
$$ a_{N+1}=T(a_1;[A_1,A_2,...,A_N])
$$
So let $N$ denote the (N)umber of steps $3x+1$ and $S$ denote the (S)um of the exponents $A_k$, which is also the number of $x/2$-steps.

---

Then, to convert this into the more common version of $(3x+1)/2$ and $x/2$ -stepping, we introduce $E$ the number of even steps without the $(3x+1)/2$ steps, so $E=S-N$.

With that, I understand your $r(a_1)$ as $r(a_1)=E/(N+E) = (S-N)/S = 1- N/S$.

---

We can observe,

- that the trival cycle $1 = T(1;[2,2,2,...2])$ to any length $N$, has the values $S=2N$ and $E=N$ and $r(a_1)= 1-N/S = 1-N/(2N)=1/2 $
- that the first cycle in the negative numbers $-1= T(-1;[1,1,1,1,...,1])$ to any length $N$, has  $S=N$, $E=0$, and $r(a_1)= 0$
- that the second cycle in the negative numbers $-5=T(-5;[1,2,1,2,1,2,...,1,2])$ to any even length $N=2n$, has $S=3n$, $E=n$ and $r(a_1) = E/(N+E)= n/(3n) = 1/3 $

---

Now to have a cycle of any length, and other than $T(a_1;[2,2,2,...,2])$ we can use the well known multiplication-formula for the $N$ members of an expected cycle $a_k$ ($k=1..N$)
$$ a_2 \cdot a_3 \cdot ... \cdot a_N \cdot a_1 = \left({3a_1+1\over 2^{A_1}}\right)
\left({3a_2+1\over 2^{A_2}}\right) \cdots \left({3a_N+1\over 2^{A_N}}\right) \tag 1$$
This can be rearranged to
$$ 2^S = 2^{A_1+A_2+...A_N} =\left(3+{1\over a_1}\right)
\left(3+{1\over a_2}\right) \cdots \left(3+{1\over a_N}\right) \tag 2$$
We see, that the rhs must be at least as large as the smallest perfect power of $2$ larger than $3^N$, but at most as $4^N = 2^{2N}$ so we get for the lhs (writing $\gamma=\log_2(3)$, and further below $\gamma_1=\log_2(3)-1$):
$$ 2^{\lceil N \cdot \gamma \rceil} \le 2^S \le 2^{2N} \tag 3$$
which in terms of $S$ means
$$ \lceil N \cdot \gamma \rceil \le S \le 2N \qquad \text{where } S \in \mathbb N^+ \tag 4 $$ and in terms of $E$ instead
$$ \lceil N \cdot \gamma \rceil -N =\lceil N \cdot \gamma_1 \rceil \le E \le N \tag 5$$

From this you have bounds for your $r(a_1)$-parameter:
$$  r(a_1) = { E \over N+E } \implies \\
{\lceil N \cdot \gamma_1 \rceil \over N+E} \le \frac E{N+E} = r(a_1) \le \frac N{N+E} \tag 6
      $$

---

Using (5) we denote $E_\min = \lceil N \gamma_1 \rceil$ and $E_\max = N$.

From this you have bounds for your $r(a_1)$-parameter:

$ \displaystyle \lim_{N \to \infty} r(a_1)_{E_{min}} =  1-{ 1 \over (1-\{N \gamma_1 \} + N \gamma_1 )/N+1 } = 1-\frac 1{\gamma_1+1} \\
\qquad  = 1- \log_3(2) = \log_3(1.5) \approx 0.369070246429 \qquad \qquad \tag {7a}$

$ \displaystyle \lim_{N \to \infty} r(a_1)_{E_{max}} =  { E_{max} \over N + E_{max} } = { N  \over 2N  }  = \frac 12 \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \tag {7b} $
The latter is the ratio for the trivial cycle $r(1)$; the ratio $0$ is for $r(-1)$ and (7a) is the limit for any other cycle.

P.S: How did you get the sharper lower bound $\log_6(2)$?

Comment: In answer to your bottom question I will have to check my workings. I'd put it at $90:10$

$90$: I made an error versus

$10$: The way I send the sequences to a metric space in $[\frac12,1)$ and then take a quotient might strengthen the algebra a bit.

Comment: ok, I'm satisfied I made an error in my algebra as I now get the same result as you $\log_3(3/2)\approxeq0.369$.

Comment: ...shared effort --> double precision! Very well everything. P.s. I saw the formulae in Elihaou, under 2.1 are the same as my argumentation above, only different style of notation (without this thread I never recognized my productformula (1) in Elihahou's 2.2)